# Error overflow reading serial number of USB device

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

I'm trying to read the serial number of a device using javax usb library,
and I'm getting this error :

> [javax.usb.UsbPlatformException: USB error 8: Unable to get string descriptor languages: Overflow]

The line is simply :

```
 device.getUsbStringDescriptor(descript.iManufacturer());
```

Someone already had this error ?

Thanks,

Comment: This could be a bug in the library. Did you try with some other device (maybe your mouse, or webcam)? I suspect you are on a windows machine - did you check in the hardware info if the device was correctly detected and read? It should show the serial number too. If on Linux, you can check with `lsusb`.

Comment: Actually I found out what the problem was, my devices are HID and javax requires a Libusb driver to properly work with...

Comment: Great - I'd suggest posting your find as a reply to your question, so the question gets marked as having a reply. It makes it easier for others...

Comment: @Romain Could you post your solution so others (me) could see it.  Specifiably which driver did you add?

Comment: I'm using hid4java https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java because you cannot use javax with HID devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error because I hadn't the right driver on a CDC device.
With the Zadig application http://zadig.akeo.ie/
I could install the WINUSB driver on my device.
And this worked fine on a Microchip Demo Board.

Yet the exception remained on my own prototype board. The VUSB connection was not correct.This works fine correctly now in the power-off mode (i.e. the power is not provided by the USB)